# How do I create an Observable after another has finished, and combine the results

Tags: java, rx-java

I have:

- `Observable<T1> a`
- `Supplier<Observable<T2>> p`
- `Function<T1, R> f`
- `Function<T2, R> g`.

I would like to sequence `a` and `p.get()` as follows:

- Wait for `a` to complete, then call `Observable<T2> b = p.get()`
- Map the values of `a` and `b` to type `R` using `f` and `g`
- Return the result as an `Observable<R>`
- The result should fail when either `a` or `b` fails
- It should complete after `b` has finished.

This is what I have tried so far (ignoring `f` and `g`):

```
public static <T> Observable<T> sequence(final Observable<? extends T> a, final Supplier<Observable<? extends T>> p) {

    final Subject<T> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    a.subscribe(
        subject::onNext,
        subject::onError,
        () -> {
            p.get().subscribe(
                subject::onNext,
                subject::onError,
                subject::onComplete);
        });

    return subject;
}
```

How should I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried something? Check `map` and `flatMap` methods

Comment: Added what I have tried. `Subject` seems like the wrong way to do this.

Comment: It is indeed. The real answer is quite simpler than that. Hold on while I write it

Comment: You could use `doOnNext().ignoreElments().andThen()` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static <T> Observable<T> sequence(final Observable<? extends T> a, final Supplier<Observable<? extends T>> f) {
    return a.publish(i -> Observable.merge(
        i, 
        i.lastOrError().flatMapObservable(f::apply));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now I don't have an IDE so I'm not sure that this code actually compiles. But the idea is this:

```
a                               // your first observable
    .map(f::apply)              // map first result to R
    .flatMap(r1 -> p.get()      // "concat" second observable
        .map(g::apply)          // map result result to R
        .map(r2 -> {
            // some kind of operation between r1 and r2
        })
    )
    .subscribe(next -> {
        // do something with value
    }, error -> {
        // error from either observable
    }, () -> {
        // completed!
    });
```

If the `f` computation is quite expensive and you only want to do it if second observable doesn't fail you can change it to

```
a                               // your first observable
    .flatMap(r1 -> p.get()      // "concat" second observable
        .map(g::apply)          // map result result to R
        .map(r2 -> {
            R valueFromFirstObservable = f.apply(r1);
            // some kind of operation between r1 and r2
        })
    )
    .subscribe(next -> {
        // do something with value
    }, error -> {
        // error from either observable
    }, () -> {
        // completed!
    });
```

If you need the first observable to completely finish before starting the second one bu you require all items for the first one you can use `toList()`:

```
a                               // your first observable
    .map(f::apply)              // map first result to R
    .toList()                   // by converting to a List you are forcing the observable to finish before continuing
    .flatMap(r1Items -> p.get() // "concat" second observable
        .map(g::apply)          // map result result to R
        .toList()               // wait until p.get() finishes. Remove this line if you want to emit for all values
        .map(r2Items -> {
            // Some kind of operation between r1Items and r2Items 
            // Beware that now they are not of type R but List<R>
        })
    )
    .subscribe(next -> {
        // do something with value
    }, error -> {
        // error from either observable
    }, () -> {
        // completed!
    });
```

Comment: Is `r1` the final value of `a`?

Comment: `r1` is the result of applying the function `f` to the items emmitted by observable `a`. And `r2` is the value of applying the function `g` to the items emmitted by observable `p.get()`. So yes

Comment: Actually, this appears to trigger on the first value. I only want to trigger the second task when the first task finishes, but the resulting stream should have all values.

Comment: The you need to use the operator `toList()`. I'll update my answer